# I am looking for a way to set where (A or B) and C on laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to group search terms with Laravel's Eloquent query builder?

When I try this:

```
$criteria1 =  ['country ' => ['Malaysia','Korea']];
$criteria2 =  ['size' => 'big'];

Fruit::where($criteria1)->where($criteria2)->get();
```

it means `(malaysia and korea) and big` but I want `(malaysia or korea) and big`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `whereIn`:

```php
Fruit::where("size", "big")
    ->whereIn("country", ["malaysia", "korea"])
    ->get();
```

Or group them together [using a closure](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#logical-grouping):

```php
Fruit::where("size", "big")
    ->where(
        fn ($q) => $q->where("country", "malaysia")->orWhere("country", "korea")
    )
    ->get();
```

---

Actually, doing some testing I notice that passing an array with multiple values already creates a group with parentheses. So the absolute easiest answer, given your existing code, is to simply use `orWhere()` instead of `where()`:

```php
$criteria1 =  ['country' => 'malaysia' , 'country ' => 'korea'];
$criteria2 =  ['size' => 'big'];

Fruit::orWhere($criteria1)->where($criteria2)->get();
```

This results in:

```sql
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE (country = 'malaysia' OR country = 'korea') AND size = 'big'
```